# Configure Multi-Touch Gestures for Touchscreen on Ubuntu 23.10 Gnome Wayland

Tags: gnome, wayland, touchscreen, multi-touch

I'm running Ubuntu with Gnome, Wayland (Default Installation 23.10).
Touchscreen is running perfect. Multi-Touch Gestures are working out of the box but they are not really nice, or complete.

There is no possibility like "two finger click" to emulated right mouse click.
Also I want to implement - if possible - more gestures like in Android (Swipe left to go back ...)
In Shotwell it's not even possible to open a photo, what is normally a normal mouse left double-click

Touchegg seems to have no Wayland support.
Than I read about Fusuma (https://github.com/iberianpig/fusuma) but I don't know, if this is a (working) solution and it seems complicated. Not sure what to install and configure on my system setup.

All i found was X11-based, not Wayland. Going back to X11 is no option.